# How to parse a stringified linq expression to an object?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have tried using the `DynamicExpressionParser`'s `ParseLambda` method, and managed to easily parse stringified expressions (ie: `x=> X.Name == "John"` or `x=> x.Name.Contains("John")`), which work great for `Where` conditions. But my problem lies in trying to parse an expression to a `Select`, where I want to return an anonymous object based on the data found.

Example:

```
myList.Select(p=> new { p.Name, p.LastName })
```

Basically, I only got string expressions like these working:

```
myList.Where("p=> p.Name == \"John\"");
```

And what I want is this:

```
myList.Select("p=> new { p.Name, p.LastName }")
```

Iv tried several overloads of the *ParseLambda* method, but I got all kinds of exception. I am following the [guidelines from their github repository](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions).

Using the example given with [Data Object Initializers](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#user-content-data-object-initializers) (customers.Select("new(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");) only works for typed classes, not anonymous objects like I'm trying to do.

I also managed to get this working previously using [CSharpScript](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Scripting/CSharp/CSharpScript.cs) (`EvaluateAsync` method), but the parsing times are horrendous (about 20 times slower), as it is pretty much compiling code again. So, I'm looking for alternatives.

To clarify why using `Data Object Initializers` didn't work, here are some examples of attempted code:

[image: error A]

[image: error B]

Which both resulted in `NullReferenceExceptions`.

And a bunch of others that I can't easily replicate without doing major changes to the code.

Comment: Lets say you get this working and return the anonymous object, how do you think you are going to actually use it?

Comment: I'm already using this to return data, but using hardcoded expressions. In this new situation, I will get the parameters from an Api, will write down the resulting expression and parse it so it can be used on a *Select* method.

Comment: the first example in their documentation has `.Select("new(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");` why aren't you using that syntax to create your object?

Comment: I have tried that, in several different ways, but I got different kinds of exceptions using that exact syntax. The expression couldnt convert "new anonymous object" to an object.

Comment: ok well if you don't show us what you tried and what error you got then it is hard to help.

Comment: That example only works for *typed* classes.

Comment: I don't see how pasting a long list of everything I have tried would be beneficial to the question.

Comment: it would be beneficial if you want an answer.  People on stack overflow are not here to work for free, we are here to help people who have a specific problem.  If you post code that should work according to the documentation but does not someone will help.  If you just say "show me the codez" people will tend to ignore you.

Comment: I explained why it doesn't work. I'm not saying it didn't work because the method is wrong. And if I wanted people to copy+paste my code to show me my mistakes, I wouldn't come here looking for an answer, Iv been doing that myself for a while now. I'm looking for advice from people who had similar experiences in the past and know (or have an idea) on how to solve it.

Comment: Note that what `new(fields)` does **is exactly the same** as how the compiler handles anonymous classes (assuming data classes with matching fields are merged). What do you find wrong with it? (BTW, anonymous objects are _typed data classes_ just like these.)